# Parse a string, create single strings and compare them to a value in an if statement?

Tags: java, string, parsing, if-statement, java1.4

I'm trying to do something that might seem simple do you but I'm kind of stuck and I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

So basically what I want to do is parse string str and create smaller strings and compare them to something in an if statement

```
    String str = ("1, 2, 3);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()){
        //instead of printing the element I want to generate str[i] or something of the sort
        System.out.print(st.nextElemenet());
    }

    //then I want to do this as many times as I have str[i]
    if(str1 == 2 || str2 == 3 || str3 == 3){
    //do something
    }
```

Basically I want to parse a string, generate a bunch of smaller strings and use them in an if statement. Any ideas? Sorry if it seems like a simple question but I'm kind of stuck lol

PS Java 1.4 doesn't support .split and it needs to be in java 1.4 ^_^
I can make an ArrayList but I'm still not sure how to iterate through it in the if, comparing all the values of it with a given value. :/

Comment: @TheLostMind Typo for sure.

Comment: why not use split(",") and Arrays.asList(array).contains(object) ??

Comment: Is the array and it's individual elements are reused again for any other operations

Comment: @Harsha the array will be used in a single if statement that I described below. 

basically the if(strArray[i].equals(form.getCode()) will trigger a bunch of other checks but the strArray values themselves will not be used anywhere else.

Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you require is a String array.

```
String[] strArray = new String[st.countTokens()]; // Create an array with no. of tokens as the size
int counter = 0; // Counter variable to be used as the arrays index.
while (st.hasMoreElements()){
    //instead of printing the element I want to generate str[i] or something of the sort
    strArray[counter++] = st.nextElement(); // add the element to the array
}
```

This way you can add all the tokens to a String array and then you can traverse through this array and compare the elements. Now to do some *if-checks* on each of those elements you need a loop. I used the standard `for` loop  since you're using *Java 1.4*.

```
for(int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++) {
    if(strArray[i].equals("someString")) { // use equals method for string value comparisons.
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: it is better to convert array to list and then to check with list.contains("someString")

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It seems so simple now that you wrote it down.

And it works. :D

Basically I was wondering if I can do the IF in one loop but sadly I can't do it without the "for"

Cheers! :D

Comment: @celezar - Could have done that but I didn't want to complicate the things and also, it seems that Boris wanted to do something with each of the Strings present in the array, so it really wouldn't matter if its a list traversal or an array traversal.